# URL Parameters and Rewrite

Tags: nginx

I am somewhat new to nginx and am having a hard time with the rewrites.  I am trying to get:

/c/545_453453_4534

to access c.php passing 545_453453_4534 in as params

Here is my current conf:

```
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @extensionless-php;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$  {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8000;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location @extensionless-php {
            rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your NGINX server block you need to add:

```
rewrite ^/c/([^/]*)$ /c.php?param=$1 last;
```

What I tend to do is generate my re-write Apache style then convert it to NGINX format using:

http://www.anilcetin.com